# python tkinter Entry widget Dynamic Name

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

anyone can guide me of the following:

I want to dynamically create the Entry widget and assigned hierarchical name (i.e. e1, e2, e3...etc), so that in next step easily reference back to collect the information.

see my draft code below, its not working

```
bowList = pd.DataFrame(np.empty([12,2]),columns=[['F','S']])

main2 = tki.Tk()
main2.minsize(800,500)

mb1 = tki.Menu(main2)

fm = tki.Menubutton(mb1)

l1 = tki.Label(main2, text="Fore Name")
l1.place(x=50,y=5,width=70)

l2 = tki.Label(main2, text="Surname")
l2.place(x=300,y=5,width=70)

h=1
for i in np.arange(1,12):
    h = i * 30 
    tki.Label(main2, text=i).place(x=10,y=h,width=15)
    e1 = tki.StringVar(main2)
    e1 ="e1%i" %(i)
    e2 = "e2%i" %(i)
    print(e1), print(e2)
    e1 = tki.Entry(main2, width=25, textvariable=e1)
    e1.place(x=50,y=h)
    e1.insert(i,i)

    e2 = tki.Entry(main2, width=25)
    e2.place(x=250,y=h)


def BowSave():
    for i in np.arange(1,12):
           #bowList.iloc[i,0] = (e11.get())
           #bowList.iloc[i,1] = (e21.get())
           #np.where(i == 10, print(bowList))
           #print(main2.children.values())
           #print(e11.get())


b1 = tki.Button(main2, text="Save", command=BowSave, height=2, width=5)
b1.place(x=500,y=5)

print(main2.winfo_name)
main2.mainloop()
```

Thanks,
KP

Comment: "It's not working" is not clear enough. What *exactly* doesn't work? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: I am creating 11 Entry widgets, which is working... however, to each of those Entry widgets I am not able to assign the specific name i.e. e1, e2, e3, ...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet might get you started.

....

```
entry_text = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']
```

....

```
    # add text entries
    for x, text in enumerate(entry_text):
        e = ttk.Entry(mFrame, width=80, name=text)
        e.grid(column=1, row=x, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5)
        e.insert(0, text)
```

....

```
    e1Text = master.children['mFrame'].children['e1'].get()
    e2Text = master.children['mFrame'].children['e2'].get()
```